# Image to stack into loop

Tags: image, stack, imagej

I made an ImageJ macro in order to perform the plugin "Polar Transformation" on an image stack. My macro generate single images. I would like to know how I could modify my macro in order to obtain a stack.

I was thinking to create a new stack using the original stack values and insert some command inside the loop in order to add the create images. Unfortunately I didn't find any useful command to do that.

Thanks in advance.

```bs
run("Image Sequence...");
Stack.getDimensions(width, height, channels, slices, frames);
rename("A")
makeOval(293, 120, 77, 77);
for ( i=1 ; i <= slices; i++) {
    selectWindow("A");
    setSlice(i);
    run("Polar Transformer", "method=Polar degrees=360 default_center for_polar_transforms,");
    run("Rotate 90 Degrees Left");
    rename("A"+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the newly created images to contain a unique identifier, you can use the *Image > Stacks > Images to Stack* command to combine all result images into a single stack:

```bs
run("Images to Stack", "name=[Transformed Stack] title=Polar use");
```

In addition, you can use the [batch mode](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#setBatchMode) to avoid displaying the intermediate images.

Your macro would then look like this:

```bs
run("Image Sequence...");
Stack.getDimensions(width, height, channels, slices, frames);
rename("A");

setBatchMode("hide");
makeOval(293, 120, 77, 77);
for ( i=1 ; i <= slices; i++) {
    selectWindow("A");
    setSlice(i);
    run("Polar Transformer", "method=Polar degrees=360 default_center for_polar_transforms,");
    run("Rotate 90 Degrees Left");
    rename("Polar"+i);
}
run("Images to Stack", "name=[Transformed Stack] title=Polar use");
setBatchMode("exit and display");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain me the syntax of "Image to Stack"? Why you wrote ` "name=[Transformed Stack] title=Polar use" ` ? Are they general input for Image to Stack command?

Comment: @Mat_ley Use the [macro recorder](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#The_recorder) to get the commands you need. The parameters are filled from the different components of the plugin dialog when running *Image > Stacks > Images to Stack*.